# From a web json file, add up the value of only one kind of name across different objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to get the result of the sum of the values of daily_customers from different shops, the json file is located on a server, I could either access it directly or download the file from the server every day to have updated data, whichever looks like the cleanest way to you, im working with javascript. this is the content of the json file, thanks a lot:

```
"data":[
    {
        "index":0,
        "daily_customers":553280,
        "items":894170,
        "shop":"A",
    },
    {
        "index":1,
        "daily_customers":761280,
        "items":894580,
        "shop":"B",
    },
    {
        "index":2,
        "daily_customers":685480,
        "items":894580,
        "shop":"C",
    },
    {
        "index":3,
        "daily_customers":548965,
        "items":894580,
        "shop":"D",
    },
    {
        "index":4,
        "daily_customers":324564,
        "items":894580,
        "shop":"E",
    },
    {
        "index":5,
        "daily_customers":774532,
        "items":894580,
        "shop":"F",
    },
    {
        "index":6,
        "daily_customers":851280,
        "items":894580,
        "shop":"G",
    }
  
]
```

Comment: You want total of all `daily_customers` right.

Comment: @DeC yes, you are right,

Comment: Fetch the json file and use array.prototype.reduce to add up

Comment: Yeah I can help you with the addition of all `daily_customers`